# Decorate JS object with boolean annotation

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, babeljs, typescript2.0

This is just a bit of fun here. Say we have this:

```
return {
  c: p.then(v => new Client(conf).ensure())
}
```

I need to add a boolean to that, something like this:

```
return {
  inject: true
  c: p.then(v => new Client(conf).ensure())
}
```

Is there some way in ESNext or [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) to decorate the returned object, something like so?

```
@inject
return {
  c: p.then(v => new Client(conf).ensure())
}
```

how it works? something like this:

```
let addInjectProp = function(target){
   target['inject'] = true;
   return target;
}
```

or something like that.

Comment: What does decorating it with a boolean annotation actually do in this example? How would you intent to access this value?

Comment: in this simple case it would simply add the boolean to the returned object, so something like I show in the updated question

Comment: I made the question a little clearer (I hope)

Answer (score 2):

I would just write a generic function and use it in place e.g

```
function inject<T>(t: T): T & { inject: true } {
  return Object.assign({}, t, { inject: true as true });
}
```

Use :

```
return inject({
  c: p.then(v => new Client(conf).ensure())
})
```

Comment: Yeah but it's not as fancy! :)  and this is for a library, so all my users have to write that helper function, but yea, I was just wondering :)